# what kind of a data is this in javascript?

Tags: javascript

1. Can you tell me what type of a data this is? I know it is object with key and values but what exactlt is this: `pets[name]: "felix"`

   `{name: "alex", pets[name]: "felix", pets[type]:"dog"}`
2. How do I retrieve the values of `pets[name]` and `pets[type]`?

Comment: This is invalid JavaScript. Just put it in the console, you’ll receive a syntax error. Make sure to put parentheses around the object, otherwise you’ll receive another _unrelated_ syntax error.

Comment: I see an ... Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: `what type of a data this is` ... one word:  **invalid**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've quoted is not valid JavaScript syntax, it breaks as of the `pets[name]` portion, because the property name part of a property initializer must be either a literal, a string, a number, or a computed property name (ES2015 — aka "ES6" — only), and `pets[name]` doesn't fit any of those categories.

In JavaScript, the correct object initializer would be:

```
var o = {
    name: "alex",
    pets: {
        name: "felix",
        type: "dog"
    }
};
```

You'd access that information like this:

```
console.log(o.name);      // "alex"
console.log(o.pets.name); // "felix"
console.log(o.pets.type); // "dog"
```

**However**, the name `pets` suggests that it could hold *more than one* pet; the above only allows for one. To allow for many, we'd use an array of objects rather than just one object:

```
var o = {
    name: "alex",
    pets: [
        {
            name: "felix",
            type: "dog"
        },
        {
            name: "fluffy",
            type: "cat"
        }
    ]
};
```

Accessing the array entries uses indexes:

```
console.log(o.name);         // "alex"
console.log(o.pets[0].name); // "felix"
console.log(o.pets[0].type); // "dog"
console.log(o.pets[1].name); // "fluffy"
console.log(o.pets[1].type); // "cat"
```

---

Here are examples of valid property names in property initializers:

```
var name = "foo";
var sym = Symbol(); // <== ES2015+
var o = {
    literal:   "A literal, anything that's a valid IdentifierName can be used",
    "string":  "A string, any valid string can be used",
    'string2': "Another string, just using single quotes instead of doubles",
    10:        "Numbers are valid, they're converted to strings",
    10.5:      "Even fractional numbers are allowed",
    [name]:    "A computed property name, valid in ES2015+ only; the name of this" +
               "property is 'foo' because the `name` variable has `foo`",
    ["a"+"b"]: "Computed property names really are *computed*, this one is 'ab'",
    [sym]:     "Another computed property name, this one uses a Symbol rather than" +
               "a string"
};
```

In the above, all of the property names are strings except the one using `Symbol` (ES2015+).

Comment: Thank you. Your thorough explanation with code helped me understand a lot.